# Expressjs FB login without Passport.js or everyauth

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, oauth-2.0

I've been searching for hours but can't find a Facebook login solution for Express without Passport or Everyauth. Are there any examples or tutorials about server-side oAuth 2.0 FB login for nodejs? Or is there a way to use the default express sessions and let passport only handle the initial authentication without serializing/deserializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write / maintain the [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) library which does this for ya.

Here's an example app (in it's entirety):

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  application: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/xxx',
  secretKey: 'some_long_random_string',
  enableFacebook: true,
  social: {
    facebook: {
      appId: 'xxx',
      appSecret: 'xxx',
    }
  },  
}));

app.listen(3000);
```

Obviously, this requires you to create a Facebook app and setup some config options, this doc explains how to do it: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#use-facebook-login

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Solved it with another way but what a great work with stormpath? Will for sure take a look! Seems like a complete answer for the whole authentication problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's the idea =)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you data on alert ,, use FB AppId

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
           var facebookAppId = 'XXXXXX';
           var _fBAccessToken ='';
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
             FB.init({
                 appId: facebookAppId,
                 xfbml: true,
                 version: 'v2.0',
                 status: true,
                 cookie: true,
                 oauth: true
             });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if ((response.status)&&(response.status=='connected')) {
                     userId = response.authResponse.userID;
                     _fBAccessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                     FB.api('/me', function(responsed) {
                         alert(JSON.stringify(responsed))
                     },{scope:'public_profile,email'});
 })
</script>
```

Comment: This is the front end code... How would this be implemented in an Express.js app?

Comment: when you will get authentication(on alert) make an API to send user information to this API and save into your database as new user

Answer (score 0):

the only useful documentation for vanilla node.js / express authentication i've managed to find is facebook's: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

you have to set up apps (a test app for dev / localhost and a prod app that'll be live) at https://developers.facebook.com/apps first, but once that's done it's the standard oauth procedure with only a couple of facebook-specific options